# VB.Net - XML - Comparing a Child Element Name to fill a TextBox

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm developing an application in VB.Net. I'm beginner and I'm struggling with this issue:

I would like to read the name of a child element into my xml file and compare it. If this value matches, I will fill a text box with the value of this element. Please, find below this part of my program (edited with the improvements):

```
Private Sub ReadXMLFile(path As String)
Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(path)
Dim elements As ArrayList = New ArrayList

Do While (reader.Read())
    Select Case reader.Name
        Case "DistributorName"
            Do While (reader.Read())
                If XmlNodeType.Text Then
                    txtDistrName.Text = reader.Value
                End If
            Loop
    End Select
End Sub
```

I must populate the text box txtDistrName with the value of the element ONLY if the element name is "DistributorName".

Thanks to the help of Sam Rad, now it is working fine.

José.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out and report back if any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `Case` statement. I think you have mistaken it with an `If`:

```
Private Sub ReadXMLFile(path As String)
    Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(path)

    Do While (reader.Read())
        Select Case reader.Name
            Case "DistributorName" // <------ Here
                txtDistrName.Text = reader.Value
        End Select
    Loop
end sub
```

For your second problem, I have changed the loop to this:

```
    Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("yourXmlPath")
    reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None

    Do While (reader.Read())
        Select Case reader.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Element
                If reader.Name = "DistributorName" Then
                    txtDistrName.Text = reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
                End If                          
        End Select
    Loop
```

Comment: Hi Sam Rad.
Yep, it was the problem. However, in this way I can't get the text value of the child node. I always get nothing (""). So, please, find below the way I found to get the value and tell me if it is OK.

Comment: Hello @SamRad
Thank you a lot. It is working fine now.
Cheers.